# Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise. Show that if each $f_n$ is continuous then $f$ is also continuous.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

I know that this result is true for uniform convergence, but I'm struggling to find a counter example of such function.

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of the functions?  $\mathbb{R}$?  Any topological spaces?

Comment: I don't know, I came up with the question myself, feel free to choose any

Comment: $[0,1]$ will do, @GRS.

Comment: Try searching before asking.

Comment: @Sally I was on my phone when posting this. I did search but I saw nothing similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false: for instance (classic example), take $f_n\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) = x^n$. What is the pointwise limit $f$?

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is a counterexample worth keeping in mind -- it comes up a lot.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answers above, note that the counterexamples, while not continuous everywhere, are still continuous on dense subsets of domain. This is in fact always the case: if $f_n: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a family of functions, and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and all $f_n$ are continuous, then even though $f$ is not necessarily continuous everywhere, it must be continuous on a dense subset of the domain.

I believe the assumptions on the domain necessary for this conclusion are metrizable and locally compact, as Baire theorem is used in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is false:

let $f_n(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{r l}
nx, &x\in[0,\frac 1 n]\\
1, &x\in[\frac 1 n, 1]
\end{array}
\right.$